# Labeling columns in R

Tags: r

I have 6 data columns, 100 rows each, loaded into mydata. I want to create a 6-column boxplot, one plot for each row. I am using the command

```
boxplot(mydata,main="Performance over 100 trials", xlab="N", ylab = "ms")
```

This creates the correct boxplot. However, it labels the variables "V1" through "V6" and I want to label them otherwise. I saw a suggestion that the labels should be the first line of my data file, but that doesn't seem to work. How can I rename these values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boxplot` has a `names` argument. Compare the output of the following example:

```
set.seed(1)
temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 5))
boxplot(temp)
```

[image]

```
boxplot(temp, names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `colnames()` command.

```
colnames(mydata)[1] <- "first column name"
colnames(mydata)[2] <- "second column name"
...
```

Comment: or even simpler `colnames(mydata) <- c("first column name", "second column name",..)`